# Specifying separate tf.summary file_writers for training and validation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, tf.keras

I would like to visualize some scalars such as Train loss, val loss (among others) as my training progresses. I am using tf.Keras with tf2.3. However I am unable to specify separate filewriters for training and validation and this leads to the graph in tensorboard all mangled up.
My tensorboard looks like this:
[Tensorboard output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aROd0.png)
I also clean the logs before every training run. So this is not from the previous runs.
The problem is I can only set one default writer. So how do I switch between writers based on whether training or evaluation is currently being run through the loss function?

Pseudo code:

```
def loss_fn():
  ..calculate loss..
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
def train():
  writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(args.training_folder, 'logs')
  writer.set_as_default()
  model = create_model()
  model.compile(*arguments here*)
  model.fit(*arguments here*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix was simple. This can be fixed by setting different writers in the on_train_begin() and on_test_begin() methods of a keras callback

```
class TensorBoardFix(tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard):
    
    def __init__(self, training_folder, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.train_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(training_folder, 'logs', 'train'))
        self.val_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(training_folder, 'logs', 'val'))

    def on_train_begin(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TensorBoardFix, self).on_train_begin(*args, **kwargs)
        tf.summary.experimental.set_step(self._train_step)
        self.train_writer.set_as_default()

    def on_test_begin(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TensorBoardFix, self).on_test_begin(*args, **kwargs)
        tf.summary.experimental.set_step(self._val_step)
        self.val_writer.set_as_default()
```